core.mjs:6531 ERROR TypeError: input2.replace is not a function while retriveing data from firestore
i am follwing this document to rtrieve data in firestore https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-17-firestore-crud/ but I am unable to retrieve it except the type error
export interface FireHerosectionsInterface
{
    key?: string | null,
    brand?: string | null,
    text_1?: string | null,
    text_2?: string | null,
    text_3?: string  | null,
    text_4?: string | null,
   // text_5?: string | null,
    path?: string | null,

}

export default class HerosectionsComponent implements OnInit  {
  [x: string]: any;
  httpClient = inject(HttpClient);

  firestore = inject(Firestore);
   iFireHerosections?: FireHerosectionsInterface[];
   cFireHerosections?: FireHerosectionsInterface
   currentIndex = -1;

   title = '';

  items$!: Observable<any[]>;


  constructor(private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig, private CadenticHerosectionDataService: CadenticHerosectionDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.primengConfig.ripple = true;

     this.primengConfig.zIndex = {
      modal: 1100,    // dialog, sidebar
      overlay: 1000,  // dropdown, overlaypanel
      menu: 1000,     // overlay menus
      tooltip: 1100   // tooltip
   };
   this.retrieveCadenticHerosectionData();

}


ngOnChanges(): void {

}

refreshList(): void {
  this.cFireHerosections = undefined;
  this.currentIndex = -1;
  this.retrieveCadenticHerosectionData();
}

retrieveCadenticHerosectionData(): void {
  this.CadenticHerosectionDataService.getAllCadenticHerosectionData().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({ id: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(data => {
    this.iFireHerosections = data;
    console.log(this.iFireHerosections)
    console.log(data)
  });

  console.log(this.iFireHerosections)
}


}

and the service that i have planted
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import {AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection, QuerySnapshot } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
//import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FireHerosectionsInterface } from '../models/cadentic-herosection-datamodel/cadentic-herosection-data.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CadenticHerosectionDataService {
   private dbPath= '/FireHerosections';
  // messages: AngularFireList<any> | undefined
  // FireHerosectionsRef!: AngularFireList<FireHerosectionsInterface>;

  FireHerosectionsInterfaceRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<FireHerosectionsInterface> ;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afs:AngularFirestore ) {
    this.FireHerosectionsInterfaceRef = afs.collection(this.dbPath);
  }

  getAllCadenticHerosectionData(): AngularFirestoreCollection<FireHerosectionsInterface> {
    return this.FireHerosectionsInterfaceRef;
  }

}

package.json
{
  "name": "wired testing hereo",
  "version": "9.5.0 - Alpha",
  "Author": "testing more and more no outcome"
  "Description": "Static Home Page",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:cadentic_dot_net_in": "node dist/cadentic_dot_net_in/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.4.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.4.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.4",
    "@ibm/plex": "^6.4.0",
    "@igniteui/material-icons-extended": "^3.0.0",
    "@material-tailwind/html": "^2.2.2",
    "@ngrx/operators": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/signals": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngx-prism/core": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/marked": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.14",
    "angular-google-tag-manager": "^1.9.0",
    "chart.js": "3.3.2",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.11",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "del": "^7.1.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "emoji-toolkit": "^8.0.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.21.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fflate": "^0.8.1",
    "firebase": "^10.12.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "igniteui-angular": "^17.2.4",
    "katex": "^0.16.10",
    "marked": "^12.0.2",
    "mermaid": "^10.9.0",
    "minireset.css": "~0.0.4",
    "ng-katex": "^2.0.3",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^17.2.1",
    "ngx-prism": "^0.0.1",
    "ngx-store": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.17.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "protobufjs": "^7.3.0",
    "quill": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3",
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20240423.0",
    "wrangler": "^3.50.2",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/container-queries": "^0.1.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^4.20240423.0",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/container-queries": "^0.1.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "postcss-import": "^16.1.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^12.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2",
    "wrangler": "^3.50.2"
  }
}

is there any clue that would help me to complete the test ?
i was expecting data to be displayed in console so that I can render it into the web-pages howerever I recived an error

core.mjs:6531
ERROR
TypeError: input2.replace is not a function
at stripNewlines (core.mjs:13775:18)
at shorten (core.mjs:13788:13)
at stringifyTNodeAttrs (core.mjs:13593:42)
at describeTNode (core.mjs:13633:27)
at describeExpectedDom (core.mjs:13692:29)
at validateMatchingNode (core.mjs:13461:29)
at locateOrCreateElementNodeImpl (core.mjs:23095:18)
at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:22993:20)
at Module.ɵɵelement (core.mjs:23072:5)
at CadenticFooterComponent_Template (cadentic-footer.component.html:3:11)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11268:9)
at renderView (core.mjs:12470:13)
at renderComponent (core.mjs:12416:5)
at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:12518:9)
at renderView (core.mjs:12498:13)
at renderComponent (core.mjs:12416:5)
at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:12518:9)
at renderView (core.mjs:12498:13)
at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:15859:17)
at ViewContainerRef2.createComponent (core.mjs:16265:47)
at _RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.mjs:2466:31)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3080:28)
at router.mjs:3034:12
at Array.forEach ()
at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.mjs:3033:25)
at ActivateRoutes.activate (router.mjs:2944:10)
at router.mjs:2928:120
at map.js:7:37
at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
at tap.js:18:28
at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
at map.js:7:24
at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
at switchMap.js:14:159
at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
at map.js:7:24
at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
at innerFrom.js:61:28
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:14882:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
at _Zone.run (zone.js:130:43)
at zone.js:1260:36
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:403:31)
at core.mjs:14556:55
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:14556:36)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:36)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:14869:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:36)
at _Zone.runTask (zone.js:174:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:35)
handleError   @   core.mjs:6531
Show less

